# Not getting the proper graph comparison using Python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to compare and get a proper point of intersection between the two CSV files. I am using the graph depiction for better understanding.
But I am getting very diminished image of one graph as compared to another.
See the following:

Here is the data: [trade-volume.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10TpNcELVSFKQ4dhozp2BfNJQeaEfZJiX/view?usp=sharing)
Here is the real graph:
[image: images 1]
Here is the data: [miners-revenue.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CyvBdAeblIVA1yR3lsGk4OpZekRYGx9F/view?usp=sharing)
Here is the real graph:
[image: image 2]

Here is the program I wrote for comparison:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dat2 = pd.read_csv("trade-volume.csv", parse_dates=['time'])
dat3 = pd.read_csv("miners-revenue.csv", parse_dates=['time'])


dat2['timeDiff'] = (dat2['time'] - dat2['time'][0]).astype('timedelta64[D]')
dat3['timeDiff'] = (dat3['time'] - dat3['time'][0]).astype('timedelta64[D]')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(dat2['timeDiff'], dat2['Value'])
ax.plot(dat3['timeDiff'], dat3['Value'])

plt.show()
```

I got the output like the following:
[image: image 3]

As one can see the orange color graph is very low and I could not understand the points as it is lower. I am willing to overlap the graphs and then check.

Please help me make it possible with my existing code, if no alteration required.

Comment: The second dataset seems to have much lower values than the first, so that's what your graph is showing you.

Comment: @DanielF Thank you for making m understand the issue more specific. But what if I want the graph exact as shown in the above 2 images irrespect of the values.. is it feasible?

Comment: You can do a secondary y-axis as per @DavidG, but if you're looking for "point of intersection" that method will probably not show what you are looking for.  What do you mean by "intersection" in this case?

Comment: @DanielF yes it is showing both the graphs in same color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes down to your y axis. One has a maximum of 60,000,000 while the other has a maximum of 6,000,000,000. Trying to plot these on the same graph is going to lead to one "looking" like a straight line even though it isn't if you zoom in.

A possible solution is to use a second y axis (you can change the color of the lines using the `color=` argument in `ax.plot()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dat2 = pd.read_csv("trade-volume.csv", parse_dates=['time'])
dat3 = pd.read_csv("miners-revenue.csv", parse_dates=['time'])

dat2['timeDiff'] = (dat2['time'] - dat2['time'][0]).astype('timedelta64[D]')
dat3['timeDiff'] = (dat3['time'] - dat3['time'][0]).astype('timedelta64[D]')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(dat2['timeDiff'], dat2['Value'], color="blue")

ax2=ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(dat3['timeDiff'], dat3['Value'], color="red")

plt.show()
```

Comment: It works but I am getting both in same color--- blue.. see the image:  https://ibb.co/b8Ls2R

Comment: Use `color=` argument in `ax.plot()`. I will update my answer

Answer (score 3):

Both data live on very different scales. You may normalize both in order to compare them.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dat2 = pd.read_csv("trade-volume.csv", parse_dates=['time'])
dat3 = pd.read_csv("miners-revenue.csv", parse_dates=['time'])


dat2['timeDiff'] = (dat2['time'] - dat2['time'][0]).astype('timedelta64[D]')
dat3['timeDiff'] = (dat3['time'] - dat3['time'][0]).astype('timedelta64[D]')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(dat2['timeDiff'], dat2['Value']/dat2['Value'].values.max())
ax.plot(dat3['timeDiff'], dat3['Value']/dat3['Value'].values.max())

plt.show()
```